# \hbox_overlap_right:n{} vs. \makebox[0pt][l]{}

Tags: boxes, expl3

I stumbled about some, to my understanding, unexpected behaviour of the `expl3` command `\hbox_overlap_right:n`. I was expecting all examples below to produce the same result, that is, the frame box sitting at the same position as the yellow box. But only the `\makebox` example produces the expected result. The `expl3` examples even insert a line break between the yellow and the frame boxes. What is going wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%doesn't work
\hbox_overlap_right:n{\color{yellow}\rule{1in}{0.5in}}\frame{\phantom{\rule{1in}{0.5in}}}
\par
%doesn't work either
\hbox_to_zero:n{\color{yellow}\rule{1in}{0.5in}\hss}\frame{\phantom{\rule{1in}{0.5in}}}
\par
%LaTeX2e working as expected
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{yellow}\rule{1in}{0.5in}}\frame{\phantom{\rule{1in}{0.5in}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're forgetting, at the least, that `\hbox` doesn't start horizontal mode.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `\hbox_overlap_right:n` is just the same as the Plain TeX `\rlap` (apart being `\protected`), while `\hbox_to_zero:n` is the same as `\hbox to 0pt`:

```
> texdef -t latex -p expl3 'hbox_overlap_right:n'

\hbox_overlap_right:n:
\protected\long macro:#1->\hbox_to_zero:n {#1\tex_hss:D }

> texdef -t latex -p expl3 'hbox_to_zero:n'

\hbox_to_zero:n:
\protected\long macro:#1->\tex_hbox:D to\c_zero_dim {#1}

> texdef -t latex frame

\frame:
\long macro:#1->\leavevmode \hbox {\hskip -\@wholewidth \vbox {\vskip -\@wholewidth \hrule \@height \@wholewidth \hbox {\vrule \@width \@wholewidth #1\vrule \@width \@wholewidth }\hrule \@height \@wholewidth \vskip -\@wholewidth }\hskip -\@wholewidth }
```

Since the primitive `\hbox` doesn't start horizontal mode, while `\frame` and `\makebox` do, the result you get is normal.

Add `\leavevmode` before `\hbox_overlap_right:n`.

Comment: @cgnieder: Thank you both! Good to know. There were blank lines in the package file within macro definitions (for increasing readability). Now I know that I have to avoid them (or use commented blank lines) because they switch back to vertical mode, neutralizing the `\leavevmode` I put at the start of the user command definition.

Comment: Also thanks for the example use of the `texdef` command!

Comment: @AlexG Blank lines for readability are good in the LaTeX3 programming environment, not in any other situation.

Comment: Within my package I am well in an L3 environment. Something else, not the blank lines, must be the cause for switching back to vertical mode then.

Comment: We can discuss of course the logic, but my understanding is that thee 'low level' box operations are meant for places where the programmer is in 'full control': for example, they are also not colour-safe.